# Chrome gets HTTP 400 for CORS while CURL gets HTTP 200

Tags: cors, symfony

I'm using [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle) in my simple REST API written in Symfony 3.

On frontend I use dropzone.js to upload files. Request to upload API server is denied and in console I can see following: "*Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400*". However I get 200 when I send exactly same request with CURL (using chrome **Copy as cURL** utility).

CORS headers are returned though. I can see them in response I mentioned before:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-custom-auth
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, GET, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://example.com
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
```

I cannot debug it using xdebug because **Chrome does not send cookies while asking for CORS**. Do you have any other idea how to enable xdebug for CORS headers? I can try to debug it myself.

For **NelmioCorsBundle** I use following config based on their example:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin:
            - '^admin\.project(\.|$)'
            - '^subdomain\.project\.(.*\.|)(lab|int|test|prep)\.nds$'
            - '~^subdomain\.project\.cz$'
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: true
    paths:
        '^/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
```

Finally - there is nothing in **project/var/log/*.log**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `allow_headers` config option. Browser can send only **Access-*** headers while asking for CORS and all other headers has to be whitelisted.

Anyway, I don't understand why request via cURL worked. I thought that I can reproduce the same request when I use **Copy as cURL** tool in Chrome.

Comment: I think that CrossDomain policy restricttions happens just in browsers. Curl just ignores it as is used to connect to remote apis in other domains.

Comment: @Carlos but I copied the ``OPTIONS`` request so cURL should get same response as browser I guess